# linq predicate in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, predicate

i have two tables(for Ex:TableEmployee,TableSal) with no relationship,
and i have to write predicate using these two tables,

TableEmployees:This table contains Name, DepartmentId columns

TableSal: this table contains Name,DepartmentId,TotalSal

Question:
i have to write predicate for "is DepartmentId in TableSal Matches with any DepartmentId in TableEmployees"

i've tried these methods but getting erors,

Method1:

```
predicate = predicate.And(
      n => context.Tbl_Sal
        .Where(d => d.DepartmentId.HasValue)
        .Select(i => i.DepartmentId)
        .Equals(n.DepartmentId)
      );
```

Method2:

```
predicate = predicate.And(
   n => context.Tbl_Sal
      .Where(d => d.DepartmentId.HasValue)
      .ToList().Find(d => d.DepartmentId == n.DepartmentId) != null);
```

How can i write Predicate.... for this situation....

Comment: I've formatted your code, but it is unclear what is the type of `predicate` and what errors you are getting - please edit your post with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you're dealing with raw expressions. Using linq, you could do:

```
var query = context.TableSal
           .Where(d => context.TableEmployees.Where(e => e.DepartmentId.HasValue)
                      .Select(e => e.DepartmentId)
                      .Contains(d.DepartmentId));
```

which gives you all `TableSal` records of which `DepartmentId` is in the `DepartmentId`s of `TableEmployees`.